# How to prevent the keyboard cover over the UI in windows phone?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

The project is based on wp 7.5.

I have a grid, and when the user swipe it, a textbox will reveal and the keyboard will show.

The function is ok, but there is a little bug, when the system keyboard show, it will cover over the textbox, so the user can't see the stuff they have entered.

how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to position such a textbox so that it would not be obscured when the keyboard is shown. This is typically done by placing it at (or near) the top of the page.

Depending on how you've structured your XAML the default behaviour of the phone should scroll the content so that it is not obscured by the keyboard. Without being able to see you code I couldn't say why this isn't happening.
Alternatively you could but the page content inside a `ScrollViewer` and manually scroll it so that the `TextBox` is visible when it has focus.